# Flip a fair coin 5 times. What is the probability that heads never occurs twice in a row?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This question has been asked and answered before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630656/). However, my solution does not match the answer, and I want to know how my logic is wrong.

> I flip a fair coin 5 times in a row. What is the probability that heads never occurs twice in a row?

The answer, according to the other SO answer, is $13/32$.

**My approach:** No two heads in a row means we also cannot have three heads in a row or four or five. Notice that these two events are equivalent:

$$
\{\text{no HH}\}
\\
=
\\
\{\text{not (exactly HH or not exactly HHH or exactly HHHH)}\}
\\
=
\\
\{\text{not exactly HH and not exactly HHH and not exactly HHHH}\}.
$$

We can then express these as complementary probabilities:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(\text{no HH})
&= \mathbb{P}(\text{not exactly HH})
\\
&\quad\times \mathbb{P}(\text{not exactly HHH})
\\
&\quad\times \mathbb{P}(\text{not exactly HHHH})
\\
&\quad\times \mathbb{P}(\text{not exactly HHHHH})
\\\\
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(\text{exactly HH})
\\
&\quad\times 1 - \mathbb{P}(\text{exactly HHH})
\\
&\quad\times 1 - \mathbb{P}(\text{exactly HHHH})
\\
&\quad\times 1 - \mathbb{P}(\text{exactly HHHHH})
\end{aligned}
$$

We can easily compute these probabilities:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(\text{exactly HH}) &= \frac{4}{2^5}
\\
\mathbb{P}(\text{exactly HHH}) &= \frac{3}{2^5}
\\
\mathbb{P}(\text{exactly HHHH}) &= \frac{2}{2^5}
\\
\mathbb{P}(\text{exactly HHHHH}) &= \frac{1}{2^5}
\end{aligned}
$$

So the probability of no double any heads anywhere in the sequence is:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{4} \Big(1 - \frac{i}{2^5}\Big) \approx 0.720
$$

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which of your four terms covers the `HHTHH` case?

Comment: To start, $\Pr(A\cap B)\neq \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$.  That is only true for independent events.  Whats more, I expect you intended to have added instead of multiplied, using $\Pr(A\sqcup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ for disjoint $A$ and $B$ (*$\sqcup$ used to emphasize that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint*).  Next, I don't see how you calculated $\Pr(\text{exactly HHH})$ but that doesn't look right either.  There are more than $3$ ways to have a string of exactly three heads in a row.  I count five ways, not three.  HHHTT, HHHTH, THHHT, TTHHH, HTHHH.

Comment: It is rather easy to count directly by brute force here since the numbers are so small.  `TTTTT`, `TTTTH`, `TTTHT`, `TTHTT`, `THTTT`, `HTTTT`, `TTHTH`, `THTTH`, `THTHT`, `HTTTH`, `HTTHT`, `HTHTT` and `HTHTH`, giving $13$ valid strings of flips avoiding adjacent heads.  This can be accomplished rather easily using recurrence relations as well, there being $a_0=1, a_1=2$ and $a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ valid strings (*giving $a_2=2+1=3,~a_3=3+2=5,~a_4=5+3=8$ and $a_5=8+5=13$ valid strings*)

Comment: Maybe you saw how nicely HHHHH and HHHH worked without appreciating that for shorter strings of specific length, you have to account for multiple possibilities. THHTX where X can be anything is actually two possibilities. As pointed out by redroid, you would also have to worry about double counting if you proceeded in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability for heads occurring twice in the row equals the probability for tails occurring twice in a row.  Let $A$ represent the first event, and $B$ the later.  $$\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(B)$$

The only outcomes where both occur are: $\small\sf HHHTT, HHTTT,HHTTH, THHTT, TTHHT, TTTHH$
$$\mathsf P(A\cap B)=3/2^4$$

The only outcomes where neither occurs are: $\small\sf HTHTH, THTHT$.$$1-\mathsf P(A\cup B)=1/2^4\\\mathsf P(A\cup B)=(2^4-1)/2^4$$

So, since  $\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)=\mathsf P(A\cup B)+\mathsf P(A\cap B)$, therefore, we can readily find $\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement})$.